# C pasting tokens in MACROS for processing bit fields in C

Tags: c, macros, token

I am looking for to access bit fields based on number which is passed to macro as argument. I am getting the error when I use the below code. Is there any way to fix this?
 "error: request for member 'biti' in something not a structure or union"

```
struct 
      {

        int bit0 :1;
        int bit1 :1;
        int bit2 :1;
        int bit3 :1;
        int bit4 :1;
        int bit5 :1;
        int bit6 :1;
        int bit7 :1;
      }a_type;

a_type b;


#define get_bit_value(x) b.bit##x

for(i=0; i<=7 ;i++)
 {
int temp;
temp = get_bit_value(i);
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the variable `i` only has a value during runtime. During parsing (when the macros are being evaluated), `i` is just a token. The compiler has no idea that `i` is even a variable, let alone one that is an integer between 0 and 7.

Another way to look at it is to see just what the compiler does, and what the code looks like during preprocessing:

```
for(i=0; i<=7 ;i++)
{
  int temp;
  temp = b.bit##i;
  ...
}
```

The `##` concatenation literally appends the text `i` to the text `b.bit`, resulting in the expression `b.biti`, which generates the error you mentioned.

AFAIK there's no way to access an arbitrary bit field member - an alternative would be to just use bitwise arithmetic (after all, this is how the compiler generates accesses for bit fields anyway).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to fix this?

I fear no but can you use an array instead, something like this?

```
int type[8] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};

#define get_bit_value(x) type[x]

for(int i=0; i<8 ;i++)
{
 int temp;
 temp = get_bit_value(i);
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks..but isnt that memory consuming when working with lots of structures and 64 bit integers? so, I am looking for above implementation. also another way i think of using bit manipulations like (a & (1<<n)). but when I try to access lots of times it increases cycle consumption for doing & operation many times

Comment: @user2218872 Bit manipulation is what bit field code gets translated to anyway, usually; you're just generating the `>>` and `&` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the way to do it.

```
 #define get_bit_value(b, x)  (((b)&(1 << (x)))!=0)

 #define set_bit_value(b, x)  ((b)|=(1 << (x)))

 uint8_t v = 0;

 set_bit_value(v, 5);
```

This is the normal way to do it. The bitfield you used has several drawbacks:

- as you noticed, you can not index on it.
- the size is limited at compile time. With the explicit masking it's easy to extend to any size.
- it's not portable! (the order of the bits are not defined by the standard).

and the code generated is the same anyway as the processor will also have to do the shifting and masking to access the bits.

TL;DR don't use bitfields for bit access of words, it's not the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a more complicated macro, and it can't be based on pasting. It will have to be based on selection:

```
#define get_bit_value(i) ((i) < 4                              \
                          ? ((i) < 2                           \
                             ? ((i) < 1 ? b.bit0 : b.bit1)     \
                             : ((i) < 3 ? b.bit2 : b.bit3))    \
                          : ((i) < 6                           \
                             ? ((i) < 5 ? b.bit4 : b.bit5)     \
                             : ((i) < 7 ? b.bit6 : b.bit7)))
```

But, an inline function with a `switch` will probably serve you better:

```
inline int get_bit_value (int i) {
    switch (i) {
    case 0: return b.bit0;
    case 1: return b.bit1;
    case 2: return b.bit2;
    case 3: return b.bit3;
    case 4: return b.bit4;
    case 5: return b.bit5;
    case 6: return b.bit6;
    case 7: return b.bit7;
    default: assert(0 <= i && i < 8);
    }
}
```